# A short story about a soldier in the future

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi, warfare

Looking for a short story about a soldier in the future on a mission. At a certain point he bites down on a banana shaped capsule under his tongue and the drug accelerates his metabolism for the mission. at the end he lies with the other soldiers twitching and burnt out on the ground waiting for recovery, Prob 1950's or 60's. Thought it was called "Soldier, Soldier" but can't find it. It was not "Soldier of the future" 
Thanks

Comment: It's not "Soldier, Soldier" [by Simon R. Green](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1769216) and the other story with the same name ([on ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?221) (by Bruce Boston) was written far too late

Comment: There's a book called "Tiger, Tiger" which takes place in the future and which features accelerated metabolism, but other than that and the double word in the title, no match.

Comment: I don't remember the "banana shaped" bit specifically but if you're not certain it was a short story it could be Heinlein's *Starship Troopers* or perhaps one of Harry Harrison's *Bill, the Galactic Hero* series.  (Or perhaps an excerpt, condensation, or short story that was later expanded into a novel?)  Do you remember what the tone was like?  Was it serious, satirical, humourous, ... ?

Comment: Can anybody identify the story "Soldier of the Future" which the OP has ruled out? I can't find a story by that title in the ISFDB.

Comment: There is a story called "Soldier From Tomorrow"by Harlan Ellison, Later used in the Outer Limits as "Soldier"

Answer (score 2):

**[Hearts and Engines](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?493201)** by Brian Aldiss

The soldiers are enhanced by the use of various drugs. They go out on a mission while carrying a special boomerang shaped drug capsule under their tongue. Upon command, they eat the drug, which gives them hyper-speed. They run so fast they are difficult to be targeted, and they can pull the trigger of their weapons much faster than the enemy. Side effect is it caused the sound of gunfire to damage their hearing.